# Hide the_meta if no value

Tags: post-meta

I would like to have post-data associated to posts and displayed on my blog. I added
    
to single.php (as seen here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_meta) and all the metadata is displayed as intended, however I'd like the whole div to be hidden when no metadata is entered in any field.

How can I do that?
I'm running Wordpress 4.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if there is any meta for the current post by using [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)
So to hide/show the div you would wrap your code in an `if` statement like this...

```
<?php if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID()) ) { ?>
   <div>
      <?php the_meta(); ?>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so I can add any ID name between parenthesis?

Comment: Doesn't seem to works as is on my install..

Comment: You can use any ID, but used inside the loop or on a single post `get_the_ID()` will get you the current posts meta. Can you define "doesn't seem to work"... What happens?

Comment: Sorry it's actually a CSS problem: the div is still present but it's empty, so if I apply a background-color and a padding, it appears on all articles. So as a walkaround I'll apply CSS properties to the <li> tag instead of the whole .post-meta div.